# Google maps API - How to provide navigation links outside of map for markers in the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a bunch of markers displayed on the map and I want to provide a list of navigation links for them outside the map (one link for one marker). When I click on a link, I want the marker to be centered in the map and get its `infowindow` displayed.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://koti.mbnet.fi/ojalesa/boundsbox/makemarker_sidebar.htm) is may be your need and want.